# Need help to access data between json string and object using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a problem with jQuery to obtain each value from jSon string and modify a div or span or other id with value obtained from a jSon string.

At the start of each PHP file i have an SQL request generate an hidden input with a jSon string as value. This is for multilanguage for example in english the generated string is

```
<input type="hidden" id="page_json_language_home" value='{
       "label_title":"My WebSite",
       "label_settings":"Settings",
       "label_subscription":"Subscription"
       }' />
```

for french :

```
<input type="hidden" id="page_json_language_home" value='{
       "label_title":"Mon site web",
       "label_settings":"Parametres",
       "label_subscription":"Abonnement"
       }' />
```

this is work fine !

After that i have a javascript using jquery to match each label_xxx with value

i have many html code like this

```
<title id="label_title></title>
<div id="label_settings"></div>
```

or

```
<span id="label_subscription"></span>
```

This is my (partial) code in my javascript file i called to obtain the json string from hidden input :

```
    var _getPageJsonLanguage = function(id) {
        if (!id)
            id = "page_json_language";
        else
            id = "page_json_language_" + id;

        var json = $("#" + id).val();
        var data = bsc.data.jsonParse(json);
        return data;
    };
```

This is work fine too !

The code in problem is :

```
        data_language = bsc.page.getPageJsonLanguage("home");

        var j = 0;
        var language = [];

        for (i in data_language) {
            console.log("i in language = " + i);
            language[j] = i;
            console.log("language[j] = " + language[j]);
            $("#" + i).html(language[j]);
            j++;
        }
```

The result can i obtain in browser 1) undefined for each label or 2) label_xxx for each label_xxx
I need help to access each value of each label_xxx .

I can't obtain the value, this is my last try....

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing this in php?

Comment: The only thing is do in PHP is the MySQL request to generate jSon string, after that is javascript/jquery to read the jSon string and change each label_xxx in html code with right value label in user language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your `for in` loop, you never actually grab the value, only the key:

```
for (i in data_language) {
    console.log("i in language = " + i);
    language[j] = data_language[i]; //changed this line to actually grab the value
    console.log("language[j] = " + language[j]);
    $("#" + i).html(language[j]);
    j++;
}
```

If you are receiving `undefined`, it may be due to the JSON not being parsed correctly. Since your using jQuery, you can always run `$.parseJSON(json)` to be sure.

Fiddle accessing your JSON in a `for in` loop and logging: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/CKBLc/1/

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work -

```
var data_language = JSON.parse($("#page_json_language_home").val());
var language = [];
var j = 0;

for (i in data_language) {
        console.log("i in language = " + i);
        language[j] = data_language[i];
        console.log("language[j] = " + language[j]);
        $("#" + i).html(language[j]);
        j++;
    }
```